# Do I need to launch a compareToIgnoreCase?

Tags: android

I register a receiver using Code A in AndroidManifest.xml.

The Code B will handle something after mobile phone restart.

I think I can move the code `if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null && ACTION.compareToIgnoreCase(intent.getAction()) == 0)` just like Code C.

I think that `public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` will be launched only after  mobile phone restart because  I have set  `<intent-filter>  <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />`

Right?

**Code A**

```
<receiver android:name="bll.CleanupBootReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**Code B**

```
public class CleanupBootReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver{

    private static final String ACTION = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null && ACTION.compareToIgnoreCase(intent.getAction()) == 0) {
           //To Do...
        }
    }

}
```

**Code C**

```
public class CleanupBootReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //To Do...
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes you can use code 3 for the broadcast receiver, but may be some time it will not call if you application is no longer used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think I can move the code if (intent != null && intent.getAction()
>   != null && ACTION.compareToIgnoreCase(intent.getAction()) == 0) just
>   like Code C.

Yes you can, because you are using your receiver for only one intent-filter action.

But your broadcast receiver can still be triggered using explicit events like

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(context, CleanupBootReceiver.class)
```

so it is good idea to keep with conditional match though I recommend you to use `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `compareToIgnoreCase`

> I think that public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
>   will be launched only after mobile phone restart because I have set

```
<intent-filter>  <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Yes though a [must read : Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background)